# How do I create a link in the node template?

Tags: theming

I have a *news* content type, and the node--news.html.twig template.

I have some fields, but I can not create links to node for text-field from teaser-view. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Node templates have `url` variable which you can use in your template in the following way:

```
<a href="{{ url }}">{{ label }}</a>
```

(See [`node.html.twig`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21templates%21node.html.twig/8.2.x) for an example.)

In general, you can use `link` function in twig template:

```
{{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class':['foo', 'bar', 'baz']} ) }}
```

(See [Functions - In Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2486991) for a short list of twig functions provided by Drupal. Also take a look at [`TwigExtension`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/class/TwigExtension/8.2.x) for their source.)